# Issues with mobile menu Magento 2.3

Tags: magento2, php, configuration, magento2.3.3, mobile-menu

I am having an issue with the mobile menu in Magento 2.3.3 as can be seen in the picture. When I clear browser cache it works fine but when I refresh the page then the issue comes up again. Does anyone have any ideas on how to fix this issue?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance..!

[image]

Comment: It's a css issue, please notice which css are applying while it works fine and which are not while it does not work.   Also might some class will apply when works fine, you need to notice that. And you will find an asnwer.

Comment: I dont think it is a css issue. It's a php configuration issue. The css is fine. When I clear brower cache or flush magento cache, the mobile menu looks good. However, when I refresh the page, the mobile menu comes up this issue.